# I have an Intel i9 12900k which has 16 cores but my system recognizes two cpu with 8 cores each

Tags: windows-10, cpu, core, intel-core-i9

[System showing 2 cpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEXz5.png)

I have an Intel i9 12900k which has 16 cores but my system recognizes two cpu with 8 cores each.

Comment: That sounds right. See this: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134599/intel-core-i912900k-processor-30m-cache-up-to-5-20-ghz.html

Answer (score 1):

The I9-12900K has 8 performance cores (P cores) and 8 energy efficiency
cores (E cores). Each core is designed differently to optimize for its
goals, but supports the same software.

The overall goal is to have low power consumption on the E core,
fast calculations on the P core, and a new operating system management
control in Windows to make the CPU run most efficiently and also
economically.

This system management control is fully enabled in Windows 11,
while Windows 10 can achieve only some of the functions.
In fact, this new hardware architecture is one of the main reasons
for the existence of Windows 11.

As Windows 10 has only a partial understanding of this architecture,
the CPU cores are divided into two groups by their differing characteristics.
That's the way that the Windows 10 chipset driver has preferred to
represent them to the Windows scheduler, which is just a compromise.
The final effect for Windows as regarding the scheduling and execution
of threads is exactly the same as for 16 separate cores.

Comment: But I have another system with same config and windows 10 and it is showing 1 cpu with 16 core when typing the same command in the image.

Comment: Check that the two systems have exactly the same Windows and drivers updates and also identical hardware.

Comment: Hardware is identical but I asked the question since you said in your answer that windows 10 can't show 16 core in single cpu, that is why i was confused

Comment: The two computers cannot be totally identical in hardware and software, perhaps they have a different history of Windows Updates. The two representations are equally valid, with I would think the 16-cores one being more advanced, while the 2-cores one looking like an earlier compromise.